# Angular pass / get class on click event

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this code:

```
<i class="fa fa-eye" (click)="passclass($event)"></i>
```

I know that I can get the id of the element in the `$event`.

I was wondering is I can get the element's class too?

Comment: Can you give more details about the element class ? 
is it an element of an array ( as *ngFor) ?

Comment: It's just this ... class="fa fa-eye" pass: "fa fa-eye" so I can add some logic into it...for example: if ($event.theClass === 'fa-eye') { //do something }

Comment: you can edit the function passClass in order to receive as a param the class name.  <i class="fa fa-eye" (click)="passclass($event, 'fa-eye')"></i>

Comment: I can't pass it like that as this class contents are going to change so I need to get it by code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get a class name like below code

```
  if(event.target?.className === 'fa fa-eye'){
                //do something
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update** : Sorry, the solution I proposed works in Javascript but not properly in Angular

In fact you could instead use template variable like that :

```
<i #element class="fa fa-eye" (click)="passclass($event, element.classList)"></i>
```

Comment: I'm getting:  Property 'classList' does not exist